# How to override equals and hashcode to List<Long> parameter

Tags: java

I have one class attribute called groups:

```
private List<Long> groups;
```

Can i use this attribute inside my equals like this:

```
if(!groups.equals(other.groups))
  return false
```

Comment: XY Problem? What is the goal of overriding equals and hashcode for list of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your updated question is: it depends on particular criterias for equality.

Default `equals` method for list compares size and all corresponding elements. It means that if lists have the same elements but in different orders they are not equal. If it fits your equality conditions then you can surely use it. If not, you have to compare lists manually according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  The `List` interface specifies its [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--) contract and any implementation that changed that would be in violation.

Comment: Thank you Louis then this attribute is not part of equals and hashcode that will be overrided by the class, right?

Comment: ...what?  That question doesn't make sense.  Your class containing the `groups` field can implement its own `hashCode` and `equals` contract however it likes, it just can't change the `hashCode` and `equals` of `groups` itself.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation.. i just want to know if there's any problem to use this propertiy inside equals and hashcode like another single field, not a collection.

Comment: No, not at all.